# wordpress dont show post if no custom field value

Tags: wordpress, meta-key

I am trying to hide posts in a loop which has NO custom field value present, this is what I am doing, but it doesn't show any post at all..

http://pastie.org/8082255

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10881/how-can-i-show-posts-only-if-meta-value-is-not-empty

Answer (score 0):

Now you look for custom field show_logged which IS NOT like yes, try

```
'meta_value' => 'NO'
```